# Android : recording big datas into App folder

Tags: android, filesystems

`getExternalFilesDir()` is used to get the path of the application folder `Android/data/data/your_package/`
allowing to save datas that will be removed when the app will me removed !!!

I want to install a big amont of datas (maybe 256 Mo).
How can I install these datas on the sdcard (and not into the app folder) but be sure that these datas will me removed when I remove the app !

I can use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` but datas will not be removed when the app is deleted !

For example, the google maps application load a lot of datas (maps). If it was possible to remove the maps application I suppose the cached maps should be removed too !

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal):

> Accessing files on external storage
>
> If you're using API Level 8 or greater, use getExternalFilesDir() to
>   open a File that represents the external storage directory where you
>   should save your files. This method takes a type parameter that
>   specifies the type of subdirectory you want, such as DIRECTORY_MUSIC
>   and DIRECTORY_RINGTONES (pass null to receive the root of your
>   application's file directory). This method will create the appropriate
>   directory if necessary. By specifying the type of directory, you
>   ensure that the Android's media scanner will properly categorize your
>   files in the system (for example, ringtones are identified as
>   ringtones and not music). If the user uninstalls your application,
>   this directory and all its contents will be deleted.
>
> If you're using API Level 7 or lower, use
>   getExternalStorageDirectory(), to open a File representing the root of
>   the external storage. You should then write your data in the following
>   directory:
>
> /Android/data//files/ The  is your
>   Java-style package name, such as "com.example.android.app". If the
>   user's device is running API Level 8 or greater and they uninstall
>   your application, this directory and all its contents will be deleted.